# Connect Shadowsocks- sever in Docker

Tags: docker, proxy

The program in docker(ubuntu) need a proxy to access region restricted website.
and the remote proxy server is established on shadowsocksr, which is different from shadowsocks.
is there any method to connect the server in docker?
or better,is there any method that can start a local service and the program can choose whether to communicate the proxy redirect or not instead of global proxy?

Need some docker shadowsocksr guide.